# How to filter the records in Kusto

Tags: kql, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I am trying to get the event names in each department by Id. I tried with filters and othe but unable to get it. Any inputs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using the [`make_set()` aggregation function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/make-set-aggregation-function).

for example:

```
T
| summarize make_set(Event) by DeptId, DeptName
```

Comment: How can we get the count of those events as well

Comment: Got it. It can be done using array_length

Comment: @BalanjaneyuluK You can also use `dcount` to count the distinct values in the same summarize statement like:

T
| summarize DistinctEvents= make_set(Event), EventCount=dcount(Event) by DeptId, DeptName